# Angular chosen multiple with default values

Tags: angularjs, angular-chosen

HTML:

```
       <select chosen multiple class="form-control" ng-model="model.Skills"
          ng-options="skills.name.skillName for skills in skills" 
data-placeholder="Select Skills" >
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>

$scope.skills = [
  {
    "skillName": "C",
    "idx": "0"
  },
  {
    "skillName": "C++",
    "idx": "1"
  },
  {
    "skillName": "Java",
    "idx": "2"
  }
]
```

idx is index of the skills . My angular chosen does multi selection. I wanted to set my default value as `Java and C` so I set it as following

```
$scope.model = {};

$scope.model.Skills = [2,1];

$scope.selected = 2;
```

but its not working out. https://plnkr.co/edit/cQEB5T?p=preview I used following example.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code according to this code snippet...

```
<select
   chosen multiple
   ng-model="model.Skills"
   ng-options="s.idx as s.skillName for s in skills ">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```